# how to bind component variable to form object instance property

Tags: html, forms, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I am not quite sure how to bind a variable from my component class to a property value in my form object. The form needs to display this value and add it to the `ngModel` so that it can become part of the object instance.

I am struggling with the syntax and keep getting the error`No value accessor for form control with name: 'per_print'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name:` I think I need to use the `[(ngModel)]="myObject.property"` syntax, but I am not getting this from an input into the form, but from a binded variable on the class.

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <label class="label-text" >Per Print</label>
       <div class="input-group" style="width:150px;">

          <h4 [(ngModel)]="job_entry.per_print"  name="per_print" 
      value='pricePerPrint'   class="form-control"
           >
          {{pricePerPrint | currency:'GBP':true:'1.2-2'}}
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`job_entry` is my object which properties I am setting through the form. `pricePerPrint` is a variable on the class. I want to set this variable to one of the form instance properties. How to do this? I thought I could do it through `value`, as in the `value` of the `<h4>` tag, but this error persists.

Comment: i do not see here form at all + no inputs, just h4. do you need just to display dat or you want to use form to edit?

Comment: The above div is part of a ngForm group and I want to inject data into the form by displaying it and giving the form object one of its properties.

Comment: i still not sure what <h4> should do? You don't need [(ngModel)] on h4 and value is not a property of h4. value is property of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `[hidden]` input field with the value you want, so that this value will be added to your form. This means though, that you need to use `pricePerPrint` as the `ngModel`. But `ngModel` for your `job_entry` is possibly not needed. You could build the form as such, so that the object you get from the form can be assigned directly to `job_entry`:

```
onSubmit(obj) {
  this.job_entry = obj;
}
```

Also check the **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/R53277l2ejtHCxqRZtPJ?p=preview)** for that.

So your code would look like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
  <input [hidden]="isHidden" name="per_print" 
       [(ngModel)]="pricePerPrint" [value]="pricePerPrint"/>
  <h4>Price: {{pricePerPrint}}</h4>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

where `isHidden` is set to `true`.

Other option I see, if you want to use `[(ngModel)]="job_entry.per_print`, you need to assign whatever value you have in `pricePerPrint` to `job_entry.per_print`.

Comment: This is great, thanks for this. But my question is how do I pass a value to the form object from my component class. Is placing a submit button there and asking the user to press submit really the best way, when surely this should be achievable dynamically? if `job_entry` is the form object then does `[value]` become assigned to `name` `per_print`, (which is my object property)?

Comment: Having a bit trouble understanding what you mean here. You want to use the `ngModel` for job_entry? I understand that, but you cannot assign that to an h4 element, just doesn't work. And you cannot use `job_entry.per_print` as the ngModel here, since then the value will not be bound. I then see the option, that whatever value you set for `pricePerPrint` you also assign to `job_entry.per_print`, then you can use `job_entry.per_print` as ngModel: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Ml4ykN3Ni0UrlYqncA5?p=preview

Comment: Yes that looks better. Thanks. Now `per_print` is appearing in `job_entry` . No need for `submit` as I have other parts to the form. If I can set the values in my component class, input now seems redundant. Object `job_entry` can be given values outside the form, before being submitted and I can display whatever I like on the form. I was absolute that the form was the entity that both owned the object and its submission. Live and let learn....Thanks @AJT

Comment: Okay, see, from your question you mentioned you want it to be part of the form object, so that's why I gave the answer I did (hidden input field). So yes, it's absolutely redundant if that is not what you need (setting values in component is enough) :)

Comment: @godhar if the issue is solved, you can mark an answer -that's been helpful- as accepted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/346766